# Matplotlib won't print the values in a list in the order they occur in

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to print the values in a numpy array in a Matplotlib bar chart but Matplotlib insists on printing them in the wrong order. I have re-ordered the values and the category names and stored them in numpy arrays to preserve their order but when I give them to the plt.bar() function it insists on printing them in their original order.

I tried printing out the values of values_arr and confirmed they were in the order I wanted them in but that is not the order that the bars are rendered in. I have tried `plt.clf()` and `plt.cla()` to get rid of the original values but to no avail.

`values_arr`

returns

`array([ 0.09651863, -0.05389129, -0.04672919,  0.01236926, -0.00995986,-0.00729804, -0.00545791,  0.00503968,  0.00485096,  0.00381371,-0.00244895,  0.00206346,  0.00099744, -0.00090517,  0.00078678,0.00029441, -0.00026074,  0.00021683])`

And `category_arr` is

`[1, 8, 5, 11, 3, 4, 12, 15, 6, 18, 14, 2, 10, 13, 17, 9, 7, 16]`

But when I give values_arr to the plt.bar() function I get:

```
plt.cla()
width = 0.40

plt.bar(category_arr, values_arr, width)
plt.xticks=category_arr
```

But the bar chart comes out with the categories and bars in their original, 1,2,3,..., order. (I embedded a link to the picture of my output)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7niD.png)

What is wrong? Why does the order change?

Comment: edit > click the image icon at the top bar> browse

Comment: post your code and an example array(raw, expected, as output) in your question by editing it. Without code an known input its hard to tell what goes wrong and where.

Comment: This is mainly due to 1 being smaller than 2 in the number system mankind has currently agreed upon using. Hence matplotlib will not create axes which goes from 2 to 3 and back to 1 or similar. What you can do however is to plot strings in the order they are given, e.g. `plt.bar(["Cat", "Dog", "900"], [4,5,3])`. Here `"900"` will appear after `"Dog"`.

Comment: So I can just change the number values to strings?

Comment: That answers my question. Thanks, ImportanceOfBeingErnest